# Sound problem on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo u410 laptop..Everything running fine except sound.When I type the command 'aplay -l' in the terminal,it shows no soundcard found.So what is the exact problem and how can I solve...?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried to really shutdown your pc , from Windows if you have dual boot, and if you did a Ubuntu software update, you can copy and run successively these 2 commands in a terminal  :

`sudo apt-get  purge    alsa-base alsa-utils  alsa-tools`

`sudo apt-get  install   alsa-base alsa-tools alsa-utils alsa-tools apturl nautilus-share software-properties-gtk  ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-drivers-common`

then reboot and test.

Comment: I dont have dual boot..installed only ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If the 2 commands have no  effect, sending more info can help to see why your soundcard is not detected (no guarantee) . To do so, run alsa info:
Copy and launch this command in a terminal:
`wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh`
Choose the upload option with tab key and edit your question adding the provided link (there are no sensitive information in the report ).

Comment: In the sound settings it is showing-"play sound through dummy output" instead of a specific output sound device...

Comment: Yes, there's no real output because no sound card are detected as shown by "aplay -l" result . Did you run the 2 commands from the answer?

Comment: yes,I run the 2 commands,but the problem remains same